# How do I have multiple functions happen depending on where you click?

Tags: python

so I have a quick question. I am trying to make a tic tac toe game using the turtle module. I have the screen listening for when I the x and y axis are in a certian area and depending on where they are, a different function will execute. However, testing one by one, I would get one to work, write another one, (functions), and that one will work but the one that I wrote previously will not work. I am kind of confused. Could you help please?
Here is the code:

```
import turtle

screen=turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(width=300, height=300)
screen.bgcolor('gray')
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('turtle')
t.speed(0)
t.pensize(0)

def board_setup():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-150, 50)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-150, -50)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.left(90)
  t.goto(-50, -150)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.goto(50, -150)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)




def top_mid(x, y):
  print[x, y]
  if x >= -50 and x <= 50:
    if y <= 150 and y >= 50:
      t.penup()
      t.goto(0, 100)
      t.write('top middle')
      t.pendown()


def top_right(x, y):
  print[x, y]
  if x >= 50 and x <= 150:
    if y <= 150 and y >= 50:
      t.penup()
      t.goto(100, 100)
      t.write('top right')
      t.pendown()

def top_left(x, y):
  print[x, y]
  if x >= -150 and x <= -50:
    if y <= 150 and y >= 50:
      t.penup()
      t.goto(-100, 100)
      t.write('top left')
      t.pendown()





board_setup()



screen.listen()
screen.onscreenclick(top_left)
screen.onscreenclick(top_mid)
screen.onscreenclick(top_right)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have one function run on screen click, maybe called locate.

That function would use all your if statements to decide which of the functions it should run

```
import turtle

screen=turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(width=300, height=300)
screen.bgcolor('gray')
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('turtle')
t.speed(0)
t.pensize(0)

def board_setup():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-150, 50)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-150, -50)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.left(90)
  t.goto(-50, -150)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.goto(50, -150)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)

def top_mid(x, y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(0, 100)
    t.write('top middle')
    t.pendown()


def top_right(x, y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(100, 100)
    t.write('top right')
    t.pendown()

def top_left(x, y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-100, 100)
    t.write('top left')
    t.pendown()

def locate(x, y):
    print(x, y)
    if x >= -150 and x <= -50 and y <= 150 and y >= 50:
          top_left(x, y)
    elif x >= 50 and x <= 150 and y <= 150 and y >= 50:
          top_right(x, y)
    elif x >= -50 and x <= 50 and y <= 150 and y >= 50:
          top_mid(x, y)

board_setup()

screen.listen()
screen.onscreenclick(locate)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to print the x,y coordinates to the console with this bit of code ->

```
print[x, y]
```

But this just treats the print function as if it were subscriptable (like an array).  So, change [] to () and your print call will work ->

```
print(x, y)
```

Comment: thank you for responding. so printing the x and y coordinates wasn't the problem. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I have different functions. Depending on where you click, a different function will execute. However, though I have some written (and they work), the newest one written is the only one that works.